# when i use drone CI,i created a .drone.yml to deploy on two servers meantime,but i get this error "strconv.Atoi: parsing "": invalid syntax"

Tags: docker, drone.io

strconv.Atoi: parsing "": invalid syntax

.drone.yml

```
kind: pipeline
type: ssh
name: default

server:
  host: xxx
  user: root
  ssh_key:
    from_secret: xxx

clone:
  disable: true

steps:
  - name: Auto Deploy
    commands:
      - echo Auto Deploy Start
      - /app/xxx/deploy_front.sh
```

how i can fix this problem

Answer (score 0):

Although not equal yours, we're still having this issue happening after a Drone upgrade to v1.7.0.

I'm passing a kv of `user: root` like you and receiving:

```
cannot unmarshal !!str `root` into int64
```

Did you try to quote fields like   `- name: Auto Deploy` already? Could be it's expecting a numeral (int to str; str to int) of sorts: [strconv.Atoi: parsing](https://pkg.go.dev/strconv).

Probably we're facing here the same issue [as this](https://community.harness.io/t/starlark-maximum-file-size-exceeded-for-large-amount-of-pipelines/12623) one when using [Starlark](https://docs.drone.io/server/extensions/starlark/). Unfortunately its fix was only issued for the enterprise edition of Drone (Harness.io). You can verify the [PR here](https://github.com/harness/drone/pull/3291).

Will update here if any solution appears.

**SOLVED**

Besides removing the user clause, we kept receiving errors. I checked for events on the cluster (`kubernetes get events`) , got:

```
6m59s       Normal    Pulled              pod/drone-s4twz9dssyd1487ih994                         Container image "drone/placeholder:1" already present on machine
```

Turns out you couldn't use relative paths in the .drone.yml file when you are running on the newer Drone.io releases with Drone-RUnner-Kube:

```
workspace:
  base: /dir
  path: sub-path
```

Instead, do:

```
workspace:
  base: /dir/sub-path
```

Builds started flowing once again!